# Something is not loading the first time user visits page, only on chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, loading

It's going to be hard to explain because it is really weird. But I'll do my best.

I have a scrollbar that needs to appear when the content overflow the wrapper. Simple.

But a script or a part of my html is not loading on the first time that the user visits the page. When he visits the page a second time, it works.

To see it, click on "portfolio":
http://chuckbox.net/chromatemp/

-> The first time, you'll not see the scrollbar
-> Click again, and you'll see it now (and you'll see it all the time from now)

I have this problem only with google chrome.
FYI, I use jscrollpane for the scrollbar, but I don't think the problem is there.

Comment: (image cache + timing + reflow on image load) issue?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not sure I understand. Would you say that the container doesn't have the right height at first because the images which are in  it are not loaded?

Comment: Thats what I meant. I haven't seen the page, though. It also shouldn't cause a script to not load.

Comment: I've gone to the page and it's working for me. No logged errors, the browser scrollbar is visible, the background animates, the photos hover.

Comment: There is some content appearing before page load that shouldn't be there, though.

Comment: @JanDvorak, Yep, thanks for noticing it, that's another problem

Comment: Concerning the hidden content - hide it through CSS, not through javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visiting the page shows the following:

The images don't have their `height` attribute set, and the browser has to wait either for your external CSS or for the image itself before it knows the image size.

You have the following snippet:

```
  $(function(){
    $('#side-content').jScrollPane();
    $('#portfolio-content-wrapper').jScrollPane();
  });
```

It calls the `jScrollPane` plugin when the DOM is loaded, but this may occur before the external CSS is loaded. This means that the plugin, when it is called, doesn't have access to its correct length unless the CSS (or all images) is already in the browser cache (and does not read it later, apparently).

To fix this, either

include the `height` attribute with the images: `<img src=... height=240>`, or

wait for the external CSS to load:

```
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('#side-content').jScrollPane();
    $('#portfolio-content-wrapper').jScrollPane();
  });
```

Alternatively, you might initialise the plugin on `ready` then repeat on `load` (if the plugin allows that).

Comment: Thank you so much for this perfect explanation